# ember.js transitionto parent route renders old data in template

Tags: ember.js

here is my router.js

```
this.resource('posts',{ path: '/posts' }, function() {
    this.route('show', { path: '/:post_id' })
});
```

the posts template has a list of posts

the show controller has removePost action. Once the post is removed I transition back to posts using  this.transitionToRoute("posts").  The problem is that posts templates still renders the deleted post in the list even though the model doesn't have it. how do i refresh/rerender the posts template after transitiontoroute

Here is my PostsRoute model

```
model: function() {
    self=this;
    return Ember.$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/posts",
            type: "GET"
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            return data
        })
}
```